# Meta width=device-width doesn't work on Galaxy Nexus as expected

Tags: android, web-applications, webview

I'm expecting that width of window with   will be the same with width of the physical screen.

On my Galaxy Nexus width of screen is 720 pixels, but width of window is 360.

Why? What's wrong? The full code of page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My Page</title> 
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      windowWidth = $(window).width();
      windowHeight = $(window).height();

      alert("width: " + windowWidth + " height: " + windowHeight);
    });

</script>
</head>
<body id="bo">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It depends on screen density,http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `WebView` in Android will assume your web page is targeting a **medium density device**, and thus, it will scale things accordingly.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) (see the section titled **Building web pages to support different screen densities**):

> By default, WebView scales a web page so that it is drawn at a size
>   that matches the default appearance on a medium density screen. So, it
>   applies 1.5x scaling on a high density screen (because its pixels are
>   smaller) and 0.75x scaling on a low density screen (because its pixels
>   are bigger). Starting with API level ECLAIR, WebView supports DOM,
>   CSS, and meta tag features to help you (as a web developer) target
>   screens with different screen densities.

So, since the Galaxy Nexus is an `xhdpi` device, the `WebView` will apply 2x scaling to your content, thus resulting in a width of 360.

You can change this if you want to, it requires the addition of a `<meta>` tag in your HTML.  For example, adding the following to your markup should result in an accurate width:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

However, be aware that you will need to take densities into account in that case.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Could you say, how to detect the density of the screen in my script?

Comment: You can use `window.devicePixelRatio`. Be aware that on desktop browsers, that variable will not be available.